# Change first three lines of a Node.js new Error object?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to create a custom error object however I'd like to change the point of where the error was "thrown". I was looking at the documentation but doesn't state anywhere:

```
/home/karl/dev/retard-log/src/index.js:237     // <--- this line
            throw new LogError(                // <--- this line
            ^                                  // <--- and this line
Error
    at new LogError (/home/karl/dev/retard-log/src/index.js:11:11)
    at Object.error (/home/karl/dev/retard-log/src/index.js:237:19)
    at getJson (/home/karl/dev/retard-log/src/index.js:406:25)
    at new Log (/home/karl/dev/retard-log/src/index.js:249:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/karl/dev/retard-log/test/index.spec.js:33:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Comment: That *is* where the error is thrown. What are you actually trying to achieve? Also, I'd suggest choosing a better name (read: one that doesn't make you sound like a jerk) for your project.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand that it is where the error is thrown. I'd like to manipulate it however, I'm not sure it is possible though.

Comment: I understand that, my question is: why? What's the problem you're trying to solve? If you're trying to rethrow an error you already caught, why are you creating a new one?